# cada vez que faço refresh adiciona 1 item ao carrinho

Tags: html, wordpress, url, plugin-wordpress

Estou a elaborar um site com wordpress e estou com um problema. O site baseia-se na compra de software - Premium , Free e para isso usei uma `princing table`.

No woocomerce criei 2 produtos e o id dos produtos criados coloquei no botão de cada table.

Quando clico no botão comprar ele adiciona no carrinho apenas 1 quantidade até aí tudo bem ,só que cada vez que faço refresh á pagina ele adiciona outra quantidade eu penso que o problema esteja no url porque mostra algo deste gênero? `add-to-cart=77` . Como posso resolver esta questão ?

Comment: Uma boa forma de começar é colocando o código referente em sua pergunta.

Comment: Guilherme, essa parte "add-to-cart=77" é um parâmetro para o backend adicionar o produto (provavelmennte) com ID 77. Sempre que você carregar essa página ele vai adicionar um produto. Essa página recarrega durante o fluxo do cliente ou você que está atualizando para aplicar CSS/Javascript, etc?

Para deixar mais claro a idéia dessa URL, imagine que essa URL é de quando alguem clica no botão Comprar/Adicionar ao carrinho no bloco onde o item tem o ID 77.

Posta o código pra avaliarmos!